# Google Cloud ML Loss in Recall: Distributed Learning

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I have two model versions trained on Google Cloud ML, one using 2 workers and one with just the master nodes. However, there is a significant drop in recall after training in the distributed mode. I followed the sample examples provided for around 2000 steps (workers and master both contribute to the steps)

Only Master

```
RECALL metrics:  0.352357320099
Accuracy over the validation set:  0.737576772753
```

Master and 2 Workers

```
RECALL metrics:  0.0223325062035
Accuracy over the validation set:  0.770519262982
```

Answer (score 2):

The general idea to keep in mind is that as you increase the number of workers, you are also increasing your effective batch size (each worker is processing N examples per step).

To account for that, you'll need to look at adjusting other hyper-parameters. Try picking a smaller learning rate to reduce the amount of change per step. Consequently you may also need to increase the number of steps by some factor, depending on your model and data, to get to the same convergence.

Comment: Ok, so is there a "loss" when the aggregated parameters of the graph are saved back ?

Comment: Not at time of saving but with added noise over the course of training.

Comment: I found this extremely disturbing. It means that a set of training parameters depends on the underlying cluster. I have a question : how about reducing the "batch size" depending on the number of workers (ie batch_size=batch_size/ n_workers) for making the parameter independent on the training configuration   ?